# How to get First 4 object from Django Queryset

Tags: python, django

I want the first four Objects from a Django Database Queryset !! I am trying to do that by slicing it like this [:4] `song = Song.objects.all()[:4]` but it is not working it is taking all the querysets.

Whole Code:-

```
def index(request):
    song = Song.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'musicbeats/index.htm', {'song': song})
```

HTML code:-

```
  {% for i in song %}
    <div style="padding-left: 2%; padding-top: 1%;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{i.name}}</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are trying to do is absolutely correct `song = Song.objects.all()[:4]`

if it not works try this method `Song.objects.order_by('your_field')[0:4].get()`

[see this for more help](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)